# Unauthorized_Client Invalid redirect Uri

Tags: identityserver4

I have an Angular5 APP with .NET Core WebApi and IdentityServer.

After the build and deploy, I am seeing this 
     Unauthorized_Client 
      "Invalid Redirect Uri".

I am currently stuck on fixing this one.

These are the steps taken:

This redirect Uri is set as: http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc

I am sure that anything related to RedirectUri are matching in value

(1) in the Database 
      IdentityServerData. ClientRedirectUri, column RedirectUri

(2) in the security project > IdentityServer.webapi
   public static class ConfigurationDbContextSeederExtensions
    {
             #region Public Static Methods

```
         /// <summary>
         /// Seeds the identity server data tables to make sure they always have data.
        /// </summary>
      /// <param name="context"></param>
      public static void EnsureSeedDataForContext(this ConfigurationDbContext context)
    {


              new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "myapp-client",
                    ClientName = "My App",
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "myapp-api"
                    },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc"},
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200" }
                }
            };
```

(3) and in the environment.prod.ts

```
        openIdConnectSettings: {
            authority: 'http://localhost:61173/',
            client_id: 'myapp-ng',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc',
            scope: 'openid email profile myapp-api',
            response_type: 'id_token token',
            post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew'
          }
```

Comment: Why your web api has client configuration? It should be on identityserver side.

Comment: this is in the IDENTITY server side.   public static class ConfigurationDbContextSeederExtensions
    {
        #region Public Static Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Seeds the identity server data tables to make sure they always have data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
              public static void EnsureSeedDataForContext(this ConfigurationDbContext context)
        {

Comment: See full error log in identityserver logs.